# Cannot create developer certificate on Mac

Tags: ssl, .net-core, certificate, localhost, keychain

This happened overnight. Yesterday I was able to work on my .NET Core we application. Now every time I try to do a `dotnet run` I get the following error in my cmd line:

[image]

As you can see, I tried running the suggested commands to create a developer certificate which are `dotnet dev-certs https` and then `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. Running both of them, I get

> There was an error saving the HTTPS developer certificate to the current user personal certificate store.

Before I ran those commands, I read on [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31749) that I had two competing localhost certifications in my Keychain. So I go in the keychain to delete one of them to no avail. I then delete the other thinking that I can recreate it somehow. Hence me running the commands above.

I then found out that I get the same "There was an error saving the HTTPS..." error for most variations of the command `dotnet dev-certs https [options]` options (options can be found running `dotnet dev-certs https -h`

Anyone know why I might be getting this error? How can I get more info as to why it's not able to save to the "certificate store"? It seems like I'm being denied access to some kind of folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally just restarted my computer. When I ran the `dotnet run` command in VS Code, some prompt came up asking me for my password to allow something in keychain to get access to....something. I should taken a screenshot....my bad. When I put in my password, I received the same error. I, again, followed the steps to create a dev certification by entering the dotnet commands in the initial question. Then I ran `dotnet run` a second time and viola. It works.

No idea what happened. If anyone can provide some insight then that would be awesome.

If you're experiencing the same problem, then try restarting your computer and following those prompts.

Answer (score 11):

Just open Keychain Access on your Mac

- Unlock it
- Lock it
- Unlock it

[image]

and retry

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but you sir, just saved my day

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

1. Delete all localhost certificates in Keychain
2. Run dotnet dev-certs https --clean
3. Run dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Answer (score 1):

I had a different issue to the current answers so thought I'd share to help any other poor souls.

I just had to trust the certificate. In KeyChain, double click the localhost certificate (not the expired one), then set all to always trust:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

run this command from user

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dev-certs
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dev-certs
```