# Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, https, kestrel

**Using**:
MacOS 11.5.1
Rider 2021.1.4
.NET SDK 5.0.300 commit 2e0c8c940e
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6

Running an unmodified `Weather Forecast` template

Certificate is not being found. Despite Rider telling me that it was set up successfully.

Deleted all `localhost` certificates from Keychain before running this

```
% dotnet dev-certs https --clean
Cleaning HTTPS development certificates from the machine. This operation might require elevated privileges. If that is the case, a prompt for credentials will be displayed.
HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine.
% dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
% dotnet dev-certs https        
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
% dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. If the certificate is not already trusted we will run the following command:
'sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain <<certificate>>'
This command might prompt you for your password to install the certificate on the system keychain.
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
% dotnet dev-certs https --check
No valid certificate found.
```

After that I have a validated System and Login `localhost` certificates in the Keychain, but the application is still crashing with an Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
      To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
      For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

Comment: try restarting your computer.

Comment: @PritomSarkar I have tried this, even updated the OS in the meantime

Comment: ```dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-dev-certs``` and
```dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dev-certs``` try that.

Comment: @PritomSarkar I reinstalled whole dotnet yesterday and problem still was present after that. To be sure I did reinstalled dev-certs right now and nothing has changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300480/unable-to-configure-https-endpoint-no-server-certificate-was-specified-and-the  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371101/cannot-create-developer-certificate-on-mac/56709117#56709117 read this.it's help resolve your issue.

Comment: @PritomSarkar already tried these answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that helped me eventually was to unlock a system keychain in a Keychain Access app before running a `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`