# Use https on dotnet core web api

Tags: c#, ios, .net, react-native, .net-core

I am currently implementing WEB APIs on dotnet core 3.1, which will be called by an ios app developed by react-native.

Apple requires secure connections.

I searched intensively on the web, but I was unable to find how to import the security certificate into my WEB API.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705485/enable-https-secure-connection-for-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: No, because in the post you linked, it is specified how to add redirection and endpoints for https. I need the steps for importing the certificate (in the post the dotnet developer was used "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" ).

Comment: API itself has nothing to do with the certificate. You need to configure the certificate on hosting environment like IIS, Azure Web App and make it available over HTTPS only.