# Unhandled exception. Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, .net-5, kestrel

I published my `API service application` to `Azure cloud`. I went into Azure api service `console` and tried tor run my service. Nevertheless i faced such error:

```
Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found
```

I was trying to follow the possible solutions from this topic:

[Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300480/unable-to-configure-https-endpoint-no-server-certificate-was-specified-and-the)

I tried every given solution out of it like `removing certificates, running dotnet commands etc` but i still got this error and don't know what more can be done here. I am really stack on it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How are you starting your webapp? It should start automatically if you link it to a solution with a single web project?

Comment: @MaartenDev Just going into Azure console and doing AppiService.exe then i see this error

Comment: But there shouldn't be a need to manually start the service, does your solution have multiple web projects?

Comment: @MaartenDev it's more like an API rest service rather than web project. Let me check maybe it just works..

Comment: @MaartenDev you were right i was able to connect to this api service means it works. Nevertheless i wonder how can i see the logs out of this api service on azure e.g in Console and why when was trying to execute ApiService.exe it throws mentioned error. Do you know answer to those questions?

Comment: Good to hear that the api works, you can enable logging in the `WebApp > Monitoring > App Service Logs` blade. You can then view the logs using `WebApp> Monitoring > Log Stream` or by viewing the logs using `FTP/Blob`.

Comment: @Arie do you recall the reason for the error and the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the suggested solution by [Maarten Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6310593/maartendev) has resolved your issue. I am converting this as an answer to help the other community members.

You can enable logging in the WebApp > Monitoring > App Service Logs blade. You can then view the logs using WebApp> Monitoring > Log Stream or by viewing the logs using FTP/Blob

Comment: This is not the answer to the original question. The question was about an error `Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found`  @Arie says that it started to work but never specified what was the solution. The answer posted is about viewing logs, which is not the original question.