# .net development certificate keeps getting deleted

Tags: asp.net-core, https

Recently, I've been working on a project which signed data using certificates. Since then my trusted certificates (Including .net development certificate) are getting deleted rapidly. Using `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` I have to repeat trusting the certificate (and it is getting deleted after 2 or 3 seconds over and over at the same time) before my application startup is done. If I can find the key moment when I need to trust the certificate, it's all good. If not, the following exception is thrown on startup end:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint.
> No server certificate was specified, and the default developer
> certificate could not be found or is out of date. To generate a
> developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the
> certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https
> --trust'. For more information on configuring HTTPS see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.'](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.%27)

It's been really irritating and I need to find the source of this issue. I also have used `certmgr.msc` and can confirm my certificates are removed from `/Current User/Personal/Certificates/` every 2 to 3 seconds.

Comment: Could you follow [the steps in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56112421/7687666) to solve the issue, it should be useful.

Comment: Yes. Doesn't change anything. My problem is losing my certificates continuously, not once.

Comment: Please update your visual studio to latest version. Then check again. By the way, you also can update your .net version.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. My visual studio is updated to the latest version and I have the latest version of dotnet too. I need to investigate the reason behind my problem (The process that deletes the certificates), maybe through windows event log or something.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, my problem was solved by removing the antivirus program

Comment: Well, that was not the case for me. I ended up using a different PC at the job, but a colleague of mine is experiencing the same problem and we're still looking for solutions.